# Manual kernel upgrade and Ubuntu update

Tags: 12.10, kernel

Running Ubuntu 12.10. I manually upgraded kernel to 3.7.0.

Now Ubuntu update is offering me updates for the 3.5.0.22.28 version, while stating that my installed version is 3.5.0.21.27.

I guess that letting these updates run is not safe. Am I right? If this is indeed the case, how do I prevent from something getting screwed accidentally by the update.

In case this is safe I would like to know why.

Thanks.

Edit: As Sergey requested this is the method I followed when installing the new version: https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/65757 and I installed the following version: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7-raring/

Comment: What do you mean by "manually upgraded"? Compiled from source? Or installed a .deb file? The latter should work just fine and not cause any conflicts.

Comment: I installed from .deb files. Why does updater report incorrect information?

Comment: please edit the question to describe the steps you used to install the kernel in more details. where do you get the .deb file from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't worry. Kernels can have older brothers.

Kernel versions can just live next to each other on a Ubuntu system. Grub will be configured to boot from the most recent one by default.

I would recommend keeping the one shipped with Ubuntu. In case something is faulty with the ones you've installed yourself, you can easily boot a supported version by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> in the early boot stage to select the version you want.

To see which versions of the kernel you have installed right now, do:

```
ls -al /boot/vmlinuz-*
```

or using the package management:

```
dpkg -l linux-* | grep ^i
```

#### Use packages

As stated in the comments, it's important to use packages rather than compiling and installing from source. Building a kernel yourself is fine, but it's fairly easy to make it a package and use that instead. It's to avoid confusion of your package management and easy uninstallation in case something turns out to be not quite what you expected.