# How do I upgrade the kernel?

Tags: 12.10, grub2, upgrade, kernel

I have to upgrade to the new 3.7 kernel from 3.5 on Ubuntu 12.10 (3.5.0-24-generic kernel default) while also leaving the previously installed kernels and allow their optional selection during the boot process via grub2.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I found this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds , but am not sure which method / version is right. I also found this one [Manual kernel upgrade and Ubuntu update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244546/manual-kernel-upgrade-and-ubuntu-update) so am a little worried that I might not install it correctly (from Ubuntu’s perspective). Also, do I want mainline or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You manually download the kernel you wish to use from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline

You normally need just the kernel image, `linux-image-3.7.0-030700-generic_3.7.0-030700.201212102335_amd64.deb` for example.

You then install it with

```
dpkg -i linux-image-3.7.0-030700-generic_3.7.0-030700.201212102335_amd64.deb
```

and remove it with

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.7.0-030700-generic_3.7.0-030700.201212102335_amd64.deb
```

Please note, these kernels are intended for testing / development and come with no support

> The mainline kernels builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Kernel.2BAC8-FAQ.2BAC8-DebuggingMainlineBuildsSupport.Does_the_kernel_team_support_the_mainline_kernel_builds.3F

Comment: Another quick question about this, if I have the 32bit Ubuntu but the system is 64, I still have to use the 32bit kernel, right?

Comment: yes, use the 32 bit kernel with a 32 bit install

Answer (score 0):

go to (http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/02/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-379-in.html) and put code in terminal

it is last kernel 3.7.9 .....save it in bookmark coz will check if there more up